# Is the Busy Beaver function mod 10 a computable function

Tags: computer-science, computability

Let BB(n) denote the largest number of 1's a halting Turing Machine with n states can print. Clearly this is uncomputable.

It BB(n) mod 10 computable?

I suspect it may not be, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137421/busy-beaver-modulo-2) is a discussion of the problem $\pmod 2$.

Comment: And [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/271834/28111) is a more exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suspect it isn't. Say we could determine $\Sigma(n)$ modulo $m$ for any $m$  if we do it for a sufficent large $m$, we have $\Sigma(n)$, which we know is impossible to compute.  Now perhaps 10 is one of the finite set of $m$ where it *can* be computed...

Comment: That only holds if we can do that *uniformly* in $m$. There's no reason $\Sigma(n)$ mod $m$ couldn't be computable in each $m$ but not uniformly computable. In fact, I suspect we can whip up an acceptable enumeration of the partial computable functions with this property (each such function would be eventually constant, but we wouldn't know *when* it becomes constant).

Comment: In fact this is easy to do: just take the usual model of computation and "slow down" the $k$th computation by a factor of $k!$. Of course this results in an artificial system, but it shows that the general heuristic is inapplicable.

Comment: @Noah Schweber could you elaborate about $\Sigma (n)$ mod $m$ being computable for each $m$, but nor being uniformly computable?

Comment: @JacobUrick Suppose I have a sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. It may be the case that each $f_n$ is a computable function but the *binary* function $(x,y)\mapsto f_x(y)$ is not computable. For example, let $f_n(a)=1$ iff $n$ is in the halting problem. Then for each $n$ the function $f_n$ is computable (since it's constant), but we don't have "uniform computability."

Comment: In this case, my $f_n$ is $\Sigma(k)$ mod $n$. Vonbrand is correct that if the binary function $\alpha: (k,n)\mapsto \Sigma(k)$ mod $n$ were computable, then $\Sigma$ itself would be computable, and so $\alpha$ can't be computable. However, this doesn't rule out the possibility that each "row" of $\alpha$ (= each function of the form $k\mapsto \Sigma(k)$ mod $n$ for some $n$) is computable, just "non-uniformly."

Comment: @JacobUrick As a relevant concrete example, let $g$ be *any* function and define $$h(n)=n!g(n).$$ For each $m$ the function $$h_m: n\mapsto h(n)\mbox{ mod }m$$ is eventually constant, hence computable, but $h$ itself is Turing equivalent to $g$ (and so won't be computable unless $g$ is) - the issue being exactly that the sequence of functions $(h_m)_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ is not uniformly computable.